# Time complexity of the following the code for(i = 1; i<=n;i++){for(int j=i+1;j<n-i;j++)}

Tags: time-complexity

```
for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
      for(int j = i+1;j<=n-i;j++){
        print("hello");
      }
    }
```

The first loop has time complexity of n and second for loop is dependent on i. That means for every i, the number of time inner for loop gets executed is: $\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}(n-2k)$ After doing some algebra, I get: $\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n^2}{4}-\frac{n}{2}$. This is the time complexity for inner for loop. Now we multiplying outer loop  $n*(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n^2}{4}-\frac{n}{2})$. Therefore, time complexity is $\Theta (n^3)$.
But this can't be right? It should max be $\Theta n^2$. Cause inner loop doesnt get executed for every i value.$\forall i \; \; \;i>n/2$ inner loop doesnt get executed at all.

Comment: The sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n/2}(n-2k)$ is already the total number of print done by your execution, not the number of times the inner loop gets executed. So the complexity is indead $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: hmmm. Interesting. What if print is outside the inner for loop? What is the time complexity then?

Comment: If you mean `for i … {print("hello"); for j… {}}`, then the time complexity stays the same (there are $n$ total print, but the inner loop is still executed).

Comment: If you applied your logic to nested for loops i=1..n and j=1..n you would again get $\Theta(n^3)$. So you need to pay attention to your flawed argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $i=1$ then inner loop get executed $n-2$ times because of $2\leq j\leq n-1$ and $j $increment each step by one, As a result $n-1-2+1=n-2$ times inner loop executed.

If $i=2$ then inner loop executed $n-4$ times ... until $i=\frac{n}{2}$ inner loop executed 1 time.

| Value of $i$ | #inner loop executed |
| --- | --- |
| $i=1$ | $n-2$ |
| $i=2$ | $n-4$ |
| $i=3$ | $ n-6$ |
| ... | ... |
| $i=\frac{n}{2}$ | $n-(n-1)$ |

It's equal to following summation:

$\frac{n}{2}\times n-2\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}i=\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n\times(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{2}=O(n^2)$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate time complexity using asymptotic notation, it's even easier (that's why it's so useful!).

In the first for loop

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
```

the number of iterations increases linearly with the size of the input ($n$).

The second,

```
for(int j = i + 1; j <= n - i; j++)
```

the number of iterations is also linear in $n$. In this case the iterations are not exactly $n$ (in fact they are $(n - i) - (i + 1) + 1$), but it is still linear in $n$ (even though the range is affected by $i$).

Clearly if you need the exact number of operations, you have to take into account the $i$ in the second `for`.

If you want to just calculate the complexity using asymptotic notation, you should just identify that you have 2 nested `for` loops that each is lineal in $n$:

$$\text{So the complexity is } \Theta(n^²)$$

furthermore, if is $\Theta(n^2)$,  it is also $O(n^2)$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code and equivalently transformed versions:

```
count= 0;
for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
      for(int j = i+1; j<=n-i; j++) {
        count++;
      }
}
```

---

```
count= 0;
for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
      count+= max(0, n - 2*i);
}
```

---

```
count= sum(1 ≤ 2i ≤ n:n - 2*i)
```

Using the triangular numbers, for even `n=2m` the final value of `count` is

```
mn - 2m(m+1)/2 = m²-m.
```

The result is similar for odd `n`.